# Create placeholders inside custom post type WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Lets said we have the following text inside a custom post type:

```
{{something_here}} is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text 
ever since the {{thanks_comment}}.
```

I know I can do something with `add_shortcode` and create the content from there, but is there a way to do the following example:

```
function create_content($placeholder_content = []){
    $post_content = get_post($this_post_id);
    //something to change the placeholder with the right content

   //final logic
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the WordPress shortcode API?

Comment: I using custom post type just as placeholder for information to be printed/email/or something else.. and it wont replace the content for the right one ... :S

Comment: I think it is possible. Youhave to use add_filter  with the the_content filter. Now in the callback using global $post, you can access the post content. If you stored your placeholder content in meta table or some where else, you can access those values from that function also. And replace the placeholders with your values. I think in this way your purpose can be served

Comment: I will try that now :D thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new content filter and call that bellow if the link which will help you to create filter.

> https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content